# How to use Stash REST API with SSH authentication?

Tags: curl, ssh, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to use the Stash REST API. We use SSH to authenticate.

```
curl -X GET -u me@example.com: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  'https://stash.corp.netflix.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/MY_PROJ/repos/MY_REPO/commits'
```

is returning:

```
{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Authentication failed. Please check your credentials and try again.","exceptionName":null}]}
```

and

```
curl -X GET -u me@example.com: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  'ssh://stash.corp.netflix.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/MY_PROJ/repos/MY_REPO/commits'
```

is erroring with:

```
curl: (1) Protocol ssh not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

What is the right incantation to use Stash's REST API with SSH authentication?

Comment: REST is a technique for using the http protocol. How would it even work through a raw ssh connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Kenster's comment, the only way to access the REST API is via HTTP(S). SSH only provides access to the git hosting layer.

You can use Basic auth or [OAuth](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/234819/stash-rest-api-key) to access REST.

Answer (score 0):

This work with using `~/.netrc` file with the ff format :

```
machine example.com
login daniel
password qwerty
```

refer to : [https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-netrc](http://machine%20example.com%20login%20daniel%20password%20qwerty)